# Why does hashing a UTF-8 string changes it encoding + ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding

Ok here a thing I'm trying hash a `UTF-8` Encoded String upon hashing I seeing the encoding of the generate hash changing to `ASCII-8BIT`

I don't know why is this any idea is this an expected behavior (which I believe it is any reason for this)

Anyway the code

```
"Hello".encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
"Hello".encoding.to_s
 => "UTF-8" 
Digest::MD5.digest("Hello").encoding.to_s
=> "ASCII-8BIT"
```

### NOTE: Default encoding is UTF-8

```
 Encoding.default_internal.to_s
 => UTF-8

 puts __ENCODING__
 UTF-8
```

Comment: Because the function is returning an entirely different string. It may be *based upon* your initial string, but doesn't really have anything to do with it anymore. Why *should* it have the same encoding?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but the default encoding is `UTF-8` so if anything that need to be has to be 'UTF-8` am I correct also I have given MD5 as an example I using `OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher` to encryt and decrypt my string now everytime I do that ruby code(TILT) is breaking because of the encoding issue when I trying to display a US-ASCII character along with the UTF-8

Comment: The only way to solve this is for now is by using `force_encoding` which I have to do in every page where I'm using that code which is kind of pain for now

Comment: Could you put the lines of code in your post, so that we can run in our irb, instead of screenshot ?

Comment: to add more, your latin1 string is still valid utf8 string.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Agreed edit the question

Comment: An md5 hash will only generate ASCII characters. It would be redundant to call it anything else. Remember that ASCII strings are valid utf-8 strings too

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack McCormack Agreed but the problem over here is that I facing a issue in template rendering where HAML read the file and since the external_encoding is `UTF-8` but then somewhere in the page it see a ASCII character which sort confuse HAML and it return with an error of Invalid encoding